# How to create Dockablepane window in CFramewnd MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have created a CDockablePane window in CMainFrame on OnCreate message as follows:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CFrameWndEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;
    //.........................some other code here
    BOOL bNameValid;
    CString strLoginPageWnd;
    bNameValid = strLoginPageWnd.LoadString(IDS_LOGINPAGE_WND);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);

    if (!m_wndLoginPage.Create(strLoginPageWnd, this, CRect(0, 0, 200, 200), TRUE, ID_VIEW_LOGINPAGEWND, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create LoginPage window\n");
        return -1; // failed to create
    }

    m_wndLoginPage.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockPane(&m_wndLoginPage);

//..............................Some other code here

    return 0;
}
```

m_wndLoginPage is an obejct on CDockablePane window class object. So it is working fine and displaying window correctly as below:

[Login window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrpfU.png)

so what I want is to after click on Login button, display another CDockablePane window similiar like LoginWindow and the Name should appear in ToolBars and Docking Windows same like Login window. I tried to add below code onLogin event handler but it is not working:

```
BOOL bNameValid;
CString strLoginPageWnd2;
bNameValid = strLoginPageWnd2.LoadString(IDS_LOGINPAGE_WND2);
ASSERT(bNameValid);

CMainFrame *pMainWnd = (CMainFrame *)AfxGetMainWnd();
if (!m_wndLoginPage2.Create(strLoginPageWnd2, this, CRect(0, 0, 200, 200), TRUE, ID_VIEW_LOGINPAGEWND2, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
{
  TRACE0("Failed to create LoginPage window\n");
  return -1; // failed to create
}

m_wndLoginPage2.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
pMainWnd->DockPane(&m_wndLoginPage2);
```

Can someone please help me how to create another CDockablePane window and attach it to CMainFrame?

Comment: You need to help yourself. First step: Get yourself a copy of [Programming Windows with MFC](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950) by Jeff Prosise.

Comment: What is not working? `m_wndLoginPage1` or `m_wndLoginPage2`? Did you Step Into on the call of `Create`?

Comment: Do you have a `DIALOGEX ID_VIEW_LOGINPAGEWND2` defined in your rc resource file?